# Adding disabled option in codeigniter form_dropdown

Tags: php, codeigniter, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to figure out how to add a disabled option in my dropdown, using codeIgniter. New to CI, and I've tried googling it a bit, but couldn't find an answer.

My code for a dropdown looks like this:

```
    echo form_dropdown('category', array('0' => 'Choose a category...')  + $categories, '0');
```

This gives me a dropdown with all my options from the variable $categories, with "Choose a category..." (value 0) at top. Now how to I make the first one disabled? I know how to make it select a specific one, which I've set it to do here.

Can anyone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but in the current version of CI, I can do a little (sql-injection-like) trick by appending `" disabled="disabled` to the keys of the option I would like to disable.

```
$categories['0'] = '(Select Category)';
$categories['1'] = 'Category 1';
$categories['2" disabled="disabled'] = 'Restricted Category';
$categories['3'] = 'Category 3';

echo form_dropdown('category', $categories, '0');
```

I am not sure if this is a bug of CI's form_helper, since it does not do any escaping or sanitizing function for the dropdown key/values. For the mean time, to be safe, just make sure your keys and values wont be coming from any user-based input.

Comment: Will not work in CI 3.1.9, as $ key will be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to use form_helper, you always can extends helper file and make 'disable' tag available. Create MY_Form_helper.php and put that under helper directory, then define function form_dropdown in that custom helper, then it will overide the form helper behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a few static options only the $options variable can be a simple string too, containing the options in html format, like this:

```
$options = "
<option value=0 disabled>Select Category</option>
<option value=1>Category 1</option>
<option value=2>Category 2</option>";

echo form_dropdown('category', $options, '0');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the fourth param $extra to your dropdown as a string like this 'disabled=disabled' as explained in CI Docs at https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html#available-functions

```
echo form_dropdown('category', array('0' => 'Choose a category...')  + $categories, '0', 'disabled=disabled');
```

Comment: This makes the `<select>` disabled and not just a particular `<option>` as the OP specified.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
<?php echo form_open(''); ?>

<?php echo form_label('Gender:'); ?>
<?php echo form_dropdown(array('id'=>'selectinform', 'name'=>'gender', 'options'=>array('1'=>'Select', '2'=>'2','3'=>'3'), 'selected'=>'1')); ?>

<?php echo form_submit(array('id'=>'submit', 'value'=>'submit')); ?>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#selectinform option:first").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    });
</script>
```

[Result - IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZwuU.png)

Comment: Using js should be a last resort.  This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 0):

This works because codeigniter pass the key as full string:

```
<?php
$field['select'] = array(
    'blah" disabled="disabled"' => 'Select some',
    '0' => 'Never',
    '1' => 'Daily',
    '7' => 'Weekly',
    '14' => 'Every 14 days',
    '30' => 'Monthly',
);
?>


<?php echo form_dropdown($field['name'], $field['select'], (!empty($field['value'])) ? $field['value'] : 'blah" disabled="disabled"', 'id="' . $field['name'] . '" class="form-control"' . $field['extra']);?>
```

Answer (score -2):

From the CI user guide at http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html:

> If you would like the opening  to contain additional data, like an id attribute or JavaScript, you can pass it as a string in the fourth parameter:

So you code becomes:

```
    echo form_dropdown('category', array('0' => 'Choose a category...')  + $categories, '0', 'disabled="disabled"');
```

However, unless you are a PHP fanatic or are using CSRF protection through the form helper I would just type out your form html yourself. It is the same amount of text and you are using less functions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. By adding 'disabled="disabled"' to the end, the whole select list becomes disabled. I just want the first option (value 0) to become disabled, so that you cannot choose the "Choose a category..." option. Yes, maybe I should type out the form myself then, unless there is a solution to this.

Comment: Try option groups, however, they are not visible when the select is not open: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_optgroup.asp

Comment: I do the following: I don't give the first option a value '' and use the form validation library to make the select a required field.

Answer (score -2):

**Solution:**

Change the 437th string of `form_helper.php`:

from

```
.(in_array($key, $selected) ? ' selected="selected"' : '').’>'
```

to

```
.(in_array($key, $selected) ? ' disabled="disabled"' : '').’>'
```

and use `selected` feature as `disabled`. Looks like an lifehack, but it works

Comment: Rather than modify the core code, it could be better to inject html or use javascript on the front-end. 

$('select[name=yourname]').prepend('<option selected disabled="disabled">Your choice</option>');